# How to toggle text wrapping in Code?

Tags: code

I'm using Code to view and edit tab separated files, composed by long entries. When Code breaks the lines, it messes with my view of the file. How can I turn off text wrapping?

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible. The feature was removed in this PR: https://github.com/elementary/code/pull/73

After feedback, I think it was agreed to bring it back (discussion [here)](https://github.com/elementary/code/issues/484)

I've just submitted the necessary code changes to bring it back [here](https://github.com/elementary/code/pull/587) so hopefully it will make it into the next update of Code.

Edit: This option has now been restored.

Comment: Well thank you for that. I hope it gets implemented, for the time being I think gedit is a good alternative.